# Вычисление числа pi с точностью до 4-го знака при помощи ряда pi

Tags: python, циклы, for

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно выполнить данное задание?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я примерно написал код, и он выводит ответ в виде 3.1415...

Пример моего кода:

```
k = 1
x = 0
for k in range(1, 1000000):
    x = x+4*((-1)**(k+1))/(2*k-1)
print(x)
```

Но я не совсем уверен, что это единственное верное и самое правильное решение
Всего доброго!

Comment: а вам нужны все варианты? Не совсем понятен вопрос, вроде всё правильно

Comment: вам надо округлить число?

Comment: Да, было бы хорошо округлить число именно до 4-х знаков после запятой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы округлить число используйте функцию `round`

```
print(round(x, 4))
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!